# Calculate formula in string

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

Given is a formula(y = mx + b) as a string and a tuple(x, y) with x and y.
I s there a python function that uses x and y and calculates the formula ?

As an an example:

```
def calculate("y = -4x + 6", (1, 2)) ➞ True
```

2 = -4*1 + 6 ➞ True

Comment: e.g. using [sympy](https://www.sympy.org/)?

Comment: is `=` strict, or you can directly prescribe `==`? then (depending on security limits) you could use `eval`

Comment: If the formula is always in the form `y = mx + b`, it should not be too hard to extract `m` and b` with a regular expression and then just check it without any fancy libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The following function works for any kind of expression (only having `x` and `y` variables) without using `eval`, which may be dangerous:

```
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr, standard_transformations, implicit_multiplication_application

def calculate(str_formula, tuple_xy):
    # Convert left and right expression
    expr_left = parse_expr(str_formula.split("=")[0], transformations=(standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application,)))
    expr_right=parse_expr(str_formula.split("=")[1], transformations=(standard_transformations + (implicit_multiplication_application,)))

    # Symbols used
    x, y = symbols('x y')

    # Evaluate left and right expression
    eval_left = expr_left.subs(x, tuple_xy[0])
    eval_left = eval_left.subs(y, tuple_xy[1])
    eval_right = expr_right.subs(x, tuple_xy[0])
    eval_right = eval_right.subs(y, tuple_xy[1])

    # Comparison
    if eval_left==eval_right:
        return True
    else:
        return False

str_formula = "y=-4x + 6"
print(calculate(str_formula, (1, 2)))
print(calculate(str_formula, (0, 2)))
print(calculate(str_formula, (0, 6)))
```

Result:

```
True
False
True
```

It basically converts the string expression to two mathematical expressions (left-hand and right-hand) using the `implicit_multiplication_application` transformation, which needs to be used in your case since your are not expliciting the `*` between a number and a variable. Then, it evaluates both the right and left expression assuming your only symbols are `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to handle linear equations in the form `y = mx + b`, you could just use a regular expression to extract `m` and `b` (or appropriate default values) and then check the equation:

```
import re

def calculate(f, xy):
    match = re.match(r"^y = (-?\d*)x( [+-] \d+)?$", f)
    if match:
        m, b = match.groups()
        m = -1 if m == "-" else int(m or 1)
        b = int(b.replace(" ", "")) if b else 0
        x, y = xy
        return y == m * x + b

print(calculate("y = -4x + 6", (1, 2)))
print(calculate("y = -x - 6", (-6, 0)))
print(calculate("y = x", (1, 1)))
```

Comment: I forgot to handle the case of m=0, i.e. `y = b`; I'll leave that as an exercise to the interested reader...